# Image won't appear as background when site is live

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a background image to show properly when my site is live. It only works when in the development environment. Once uploaded, it defaults to background color. I have checked several times to ensure the proper file name is being used and all other aspects work as required. The following is the code in my main.css file.

```
body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555;
    padding-top: 150px;
    background-image: url(../img/IMG_0234.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

When I use Devtools on Google Chrome I get the following response :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     http://josejrvazquez.com/assets/img/IMG_0234.jpg
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

The file can be found at 
    http://josejrvazquez.com/assets/img/IMG_0234.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need capital .JPG

```
background-image: url(../img/IMG_0234.JPG);
```

You live environment is case sensitive. Most *nix systems that run websites are case sensitive in file and folder names. Windows file structure is not case sensitive. This leads to a lot of confusion similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks, you were right it was the case sensitive issue. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
background-image: url(../img/IMG_0234.JPG);
```